# Нужна ли запятая перед "точно" в данном стихотворении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

...Суета ушедших дней
Точно пьянство без вина...

*Точно* употребляется здесь в значении *словно*.

Comment: Очередная "Угадайка". В вопросах нужно приводить предложения целиком, а еще  лучше — в контексте.

Answer (score 1):

Поисковик помогает найти нужный текст, пользуйтесь его услугами.

Злых и радостных людей Слишком много для меня. **Суета ушедших дней – 
Точно пьянство без вина.** http://www.stihi.ru/2018/06/08/7836

Это **сравнительный оборот в роли именной части сказуемого**. В общем случае там не должно быть знака: **Суета ушедших дней Точно пьянство без вина.** Но здесь авторское тире обозначает **увеличенную паузу** перед сравнительным союзом.

Таким образом, запятая не ставится, но может быть поставлено тире.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правы, **точно** здесь употреблено в знач. **словно.** Это сравнительный оборот. Но перед **точно** не нужна запятая. Оборот является сказунмым.

Дополнение

Тире между подлежащим и именным сказуемым не ставится, если сказуемое выражено оборотом со сравнительными частицами как, словно, что, точно, вроде как и др.: **Жизнь как легенда; Небо  словно раскинутый шатер; Брошка  вроде как пчелка   (Ч.); Лес  точно сказка; Неделя что один день. Быстро проходит; Пруд  как блестящая сталь (Фет).**

Но  при акцентировании сказуемого (обычно в стилистических целях) тире возможно:  Этот одинокий и, может быть, совершенно случайный выстрел — **словно сигнал (Фурм.);**  Во рту у него горько от табаку-самосаду, голова **—** **как гиря**  (Шол.);  Чернеющие прогалины **— как черные** острова в белом снежном море (Бун.);  Млечный Путь **— как большое общество** (Б. Паст.); Луна в небе **— как среднеазиатская дыня** (Ток.).

> См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина //3. Тире между членами предложения, §15

Comment: Но ведь в данном тексте нет сказуемого, просто СУЕТА ТОЧНО ПЬЯНСТВО и всё. Ппросится поставить тире почему то

Comment: @КрутовДмитрий, см. дополнение к ответу.

Comment: @Крутов Дмитрий Сказуемое бывает не в отрывочных _текстах_, а в предложениях, - вы не могли бы привести полное предложение? Может, это и впрямь не сказуемое, а уточняющий оборот перед сказуемым.

Comment: _Серж: Перед **точно** нужна запятая._ === ??? А как это согласуется с "дополнением", которое Вы привели?

Comment: @Серж  Пожалуйста, проверьте начало ответа. Вы говорите, что нужна запятая, а это противоречит правилам, изложенным Вами в дополнении.

Comment: @slava1947,  в дополнении говорится о постановки тире. См.комментарий автора вопроса.

Comment: Jasmin, спасибо за поправку. Запятая, конечно, не нужна.